# Is launch file similar to the threading/processing concept in Python?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the goal of the launch file is to start multiple nodes at the same time. The nodes inside the launch file can send/receive data through different topics. However, does that mean the launch file achieves the goal of the threading/processing method in python? How the nodes are executed inside the launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355748/is-launch-file-similar-to-the-threading/processing-concept-in-python?/) by [hammerli](https://answers.ros.org/users/55858/hammerli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If they are nodes, then each one is an individual process. There will be as many processes as there are nodes.

If they are nodelets, then each is loaded into an existing nodelet manager process as a dynamic library providing a function to call. In this case there will only be one process per nodelet manager.

[Here is the place in the `roslaunch` source](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py#L110) relevant to starting node processes.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0